# Computation while passing arguments

Tags: java, function

Consider the function below

the only use of `variable y` is to pass it as an argument to constructor of another object of class Variable.

Is it considered good or bad practice to compute the value directly during making a function call or store it in a variable instead ? Extending the question, lets say we have a `object foo` with `members x and y`, would i call new `Variable(foo.x, foo.y)` ? or store them `foo.x` and `foo.y` separately and then call `new Variable(x, y)` ?

```
private static Variables getVariables(double product, double sum) {
        // using reduced quadratic equation.
        double x =  (sum/2) - Math.sqrt( ((sum/2) * (sum/2)) - product);
        double y = sum - x;
        return new Variables(x, y);

        /*
         * Question:
         * is it good practice / bad practice to compute while calling function ?
         * return new Variable (x, sum - y);
         */
    }
```

Comment: I honestly think there is very minimal differences between the two.  I'd say it's all dependent on your philosophy and coding style

Comment: If it were bad practice to say `new Variable(x, sum - y)`, it'd be even worse to say `Math.sqrt(((sum/2) * (sum/2)) - product)`.  :P  It's all a matter of personal preference, though.  If the code's clear, i'd say either one is fine.

Comment: If you use good variable names it preferrable compute first and then pass the variable. This way you give the reader a hint of what that value is. Besides if something goes wrong the exception points you to the problem. For the second question, I don't think that extract foo.x and foo.y only for call Variables(x,y) is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments to your question, either way of returning is acceptable.

In classes that i have had though, we had to more formally consider which way is more readable. Usually this meant that it was preferred for us to use the original code you posted, not your commented out version.

However, i think both are perfectly readable, just please don't do something like this:

```
return new Variable((sum/2) - Math.sqrt( ((sum/2) * (sum/2)) - product), sum - x);
```

This is clearly much harder to process visually, so keep computation on returns to a minimum. The reason for this is not just for your own understanding, but for matters where other programmers may be looking at your code.